# Can a gym be claimed without beating the gym leader?

Tags: pokemon-go

Say for example there is a level 2 Team Valor gym nearby with a 2500 CP Snorlax and a 500 CP Vaporeon.

One day I get together with a bunch of my Team Mystic friends and we all decide to battle this gym at the same time. Every single one of us beats the Vaporeon, but we all lose to the Snorlax.

If enough people battle a gym simultaneously, is it possible to lower a gym's prestige to zero without beating the gym leader?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, when you defeat the Vaporeon of the level 2 gym, you will lower the prestige of the gym. Since you are not defeating both, depending on the current prestige it may not level down, so you will need to defeat it again in order to level the gym down to level 1 which will kick the Vaporeon out. Which means if you wish to lower the prestige further you will need to defeat the Snorlax.

I do not think that defeating a gym with more players lowers the prestige by more. It simply makes it far easier to defeat them.

Comment: If you defeat it 3 times at once it should have the same effect like beating it 3 times in a row. But does the Vaporeon get kicked out while someone is currently fighting it?

Comment: @dly I'm not sure about that. I believed that if you fought a gym with someone and it says -3500 prestige for example on each players screen it will only go down 3500 prestige and not 7000. I will test this tomorrow to make sure.

Comment: @dly it is as i initially believed, tested and confirmed; players working together to take down a gym will lower the prestige by x1 not by the number of people taking it down.